# prevent duplication of data in tablet in php

Tags: php

I have an array containing 30 element. I want to draw a table with 5 rows and randomly distribute 3 element from array in each row without duplication of elements between rows. No duplication between rows. i wrote the code below:

```
<?
$array1  = rang(1,30);

function RandomArrayNew($array){
     $keyrandom = array_rand($array, 3);
     $a= $array[$keyrandom[0]];
     $b= $array[$keyrandom[1]];
     $c= $array[$keyrandom[2]];
          $t = [$a, $b, $c];
          return $t;
 }
?>


<table style="width: 100%" class="bodymenu">
<?
$countRows = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $countRows; $i++){
$x = RandomArrayNew($array1);
$y =array_diff($array1, [$x[0], $x[1], $x[2]]);
 echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' value='".$x[0]."'/></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' value='".$x[1]."'/></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' value='".$x[2]."'/></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

This code actually draws 5 rows by for loop and in each row a randomly distribute three numbers. the problem is the duplication of distributed numbers. I need to prevent duplicated numbers between rows. if it possible to unset the numbers distributed form the original array and use the new array in next row? and if yes how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, you are planning to unset `$x[0]`,`$x[1]`,`$x[2]` or other vars. I'm sure, there are much simpler ways to do so.

However, just to keep your original codes, I have added a `$z` array, where you can push any var that you wish, then unset any variable that you wish, so that you avoid duplication. You can do that in your `RandomArrayNew` method with other functions too.

```
function RandomArrayNew($array)
{
    $keyrandom = array_rand($array, 3);
    $a = $array[$keyrandom[0]];
    $b = $array[$keyrandom[1]];
    $c = $array[$keyrandom[2]];
    $t = [$a, $b, $c];
    return $t;
}

$array1 = range(1, 30);
$z = array();
$countRows = 5;
$html = '<table style="width: 100%" class="bodymenu">';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $countRows; $i++) {
    $x = RandomArrayNew($array1);
    var_dump(!array_search($x[0], $z));
    if (array_search($x[0], $z) == false) {
        array_push($z, $x[0]);
    } else {
        unset($x[0]);
    }
    if (array_search($x[1], $z) == false) {
        array_push($z, $x[1]);
    } else {
        unset($x[1]);
    }
    if (array_search($x[2], $z) == false) {
        array_push($z, $x[2]);
    } else {
        unset($x[2]);
    }
    print_r($z);
    $y = array_diff($array1, [$x[0], $x[1], $x[2]]);
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td><input type='text' value='" . $x[0] . "'/></td>";
    $html .= "<td><input type='text' value='" . $x[1] . "'/></td>";
    $html .= "<td><input type='text' value='" . $x[2] . "'/></td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

#### Output

You can see there is not duplication in `$z`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 28
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 30
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 26
    [10] => 21
    [11] => 25
    [12] => 18
    [13] => 20
)
```

Based on this, you can write your codes as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some cleaning but this is a functionnal code that makes what you try to achieve :

```
<?php

function RandomArrayNew($array, $maxValues){
    $arraySize = count($array);
    $num = $maxValues <= $arraySize ? $maxValues : $arraySize;
    $randomKeys = array_rand($array, $num);
    $values = [];
    if(!is_array($randomKeys)) {
        return $values;
    }
    foreach(array_rand($array, $num) as $rk){
        $values[] = $array[$rk];
    }

    return $values;
 }

$array1  = range(1, 30);
$countRows = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $countRows; $i++){
    $x = RandomArrayNew($array1, 3);
    $y = array_diff($array1, $x);
    $array1 = $y; // It remplaces your array1 by the new array to avoid duplicates keys
    foreach($x as $tdVal) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td><input type='text' value='".$tdVal."'/></td>";

    }
    echo "_________________</tr>";
}
```

---

Result :

```
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='2'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='5'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='7'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='1'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='9'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='10'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='3'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='6'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='12'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='4'/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' value='11'/></td>
<tr>
... etc
```